# react redux login with facebook

Tags: facebook, reactjs, redux

I am learning react and found redux. I am using redux to login with facebook.

I have action in my actions folder like `actions/facebook.js`

```
 import * as types from '../constants/ActionTypes'

export function loginSuccess(response){
    return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ response, type: types.FB_LOGIN });
  };
}


export function login(){

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '172141521144545437894',
            cookie     : true, 
            xfbml      : true, 
            version    : 'v2.1'
        });


        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            this.statusChangeCallback(response);
            }.bind(this));
        }.bind(this);

        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function fetchUser() {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
        });
    };

    function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        console.log('statusChangeCallback');
        console.log(response);

        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            console.log(response.authResponse.accessToken);
            this.fetchUser();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            console.log("Not authorised");
        } else {
            console.log("Please log in to facebook");
        }
    };

    function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        this.statusChangeCallback(response);
        }.bind(this));
        dispatch(loginSuccess(response))
    };

    function handleLogin() {
        FB.login(this.checkLoginState());
    };

    function handleLogout(){
        FB.logout(function(response) {});

    };
}
```

and I have reducers like `reducers/Login.js`

```
    import { FB_LOGIN } from '../constants/ActionTypes'

const initialState = [
  {
    accessToken = null,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    isLoggedOut: true,
    userData: []
  }
]

export default function pvlogin(state = initialState, action) {
    if action.type === FB_LOGIN
  switch (action.type) {
    case FB_LOGIN:
        return 
        {
          accessToken: action.authResponse.accessToken,
          isLoggedIn: true,
          isLoggedOut: false,
        },
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

and my `reducers/index.js`

```
    import * as ActionTypes from '../actions'
    import { routerStateReducer as router } from 'redux-router'
    import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

    const rootReducer = combineReducers({
      pvlogin,
    })

    export default rootReducer

and  my container to handle this.. `containers/Login.js`

    import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Login from '../components/Login'
import * as FbActions from '../actions/facebook'

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    login: state.pvlogin
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(FbActions, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login)
```

and my store looks like

```
    import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import rootReducer from '../reducers'

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
  thunk
)(createStore)

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer, initialState)

  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
      const nextReducer = require('../reducers')
      store.replaceReducer(nextReducer)
    })
  }

  return store
}
```

and my component for login

```
    import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'

class Login extends Component{
    console.log("inside login")

    render() {
    const { login } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <a href="#" onClick={login.handleLogin}>Login with Facebook</a>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Login.propTypes = {
  login: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default Login
```

and finally my `index.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import Login from './containers/Login'
import configureStore from './store/configureStore'

const store = configureStore()

    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Login />
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    )
```

I am very new to react and redux.. I am messing with this from few hours and not got any head out..

Can anyone suggest me how to handle facebook login ..

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at this component http://react-components.com/component/react-facebook-login2

Comment: It looks like that website does not exist anymore :(

Comment: Yes, was deleted. Sorry.